# Gauss Law Problem Electric Field

Tags: gauss-law

How can I use Gauss's Law in a problem about the electric field at a point some distance from a nonconducting plastic sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well you will have to specify where is the charge located. if it is on the plastic sheet and you have all the symmety required then you can use gauss law just as in metallic sheet.